# WooCommerce product column template admin customized

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to short the description column in the product table in the admin panel of woo-commerce WordPress. Please, anyone, help in this regard.

thanks

Comment: Could you explain more what the issue is? The description length on the product page?

Comment: I am trying to show short description in product table on admin side.